# Identify triangle points around a point

Tags: c#, geometry

I develop in .NET an application that draws some lines. 
In the middle of a line I need to draw the line direction array.

Have:
`(xA, yA, xB, yB)` or `(pA, pB)` - segment `AB` points
`arrWidth, arrHeight` - arrow dimensions;
`> B` - arrow direction.

Need:
3 new points `pArr1, pArr2, pArr3` - points of the directional arrow, that should be situated in the middle of the segment `AB`.

[image]

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear about what you need? This may not be a mathematics question.

Comment: I hope you do realize that your question is still not clear.

Comment: 1. the direction. 
2. the size of the arrow. 
3. what this has to do with mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'll make some definitions.

let:

- p = position vector to tail of line
- v = the line vector
- h = the arrow height
- w = the arrow width
- L = the anti-clockwise rotation by 90 degrees

Then your three points are:

1. p + (|v|/2 - h/2 + w/2 L) v/|v|
2. p + (|v|/2 - h/2 - w/2 L) v/|v|
3. p + (|v|/2 + h/2) v/|v|

Where v/|v| is the unit vector along your line.

In 2 dimensions L is just the mapping (x, y) => (-y, x)

To be more explicit, using the variables in the question, the points above could be written in C# as:

```
// assuming xA, yA, xB, yB, arrWidth, arrHeight are initialised
var xV = xB - xA;
var yV = yB - yA;
var v = Math.Sqrt(xV*xV + yV*yV);
var pArr1 = new[] {
    xA + xV / 2 - xV * arrHeight / (2 * v) - yV * arrWidth / (2 * v),
    yA + yV / 2 - yV * arrHeight / (2 * v) + xV * arrWidth / (2 * v) };
var pArr2 = new[] {
    xA + xV / 2 - xV * arrHeight / (2 * v) + yV * arrWidth / (2 * v),
    yA + yV / 2 - yV * arrHeight / (2 * v) - xV * arrWidth / (2 * v) };
var pArr3 = new[] {
    xA + xV / 2 + xV * arrHeight / (2 * v),
    yA + yV / 2 + yV * arrHeight / (2 * v) };
```

Comment: as I am not really mathematician, could you "normalize" your formula, in order to be used by a say, programming language? like using Sin, Cos, etc...

Comment: I still don't understand... there is no notion of vector in C#, by eg... could you present it without using vectors? thanks.

Comment: That's exactly what the code snippet starting "pArr1 =" was intended for. That should be valid C#, providing pArr1 is declared, and you have initialised px, py, vx, vy, and v to values specified.

Comment: @silasdavis: unfortunately, I have no the `v` vector, and your snippet is not a valid code for C#...

Comment: Perhaps it was unclear, none of the values in the C# code where vectors for that reason, please see the updated answer now uses your xA, yA, xB, yB explicitly. The v in the C# is different from the vector v, sorry that this was unclear, please see the explicit initialisation of v in the current code snippet.

Comment: Sorry, your code is not a valid C# code., particulary there is not operation "space" like in `(2 v)` or new[] does not exists as constructor...

Comment: yes you were right, I've made the multiplication explicit. new[] is valid shorthand for new decimal[] etc in recent versions of .NET. I have updated again, but it really ought to be good enough pseudo code for you to convert before now. This is a maths forum after all.

Comment: With your question variables initialised, this does actually compile under .NET 4

Comment: your code and your "formula" are not synchronized, so I am not sure where is the right version...

Comment: thank you man, you are a genius! I just replaced the [] par `var pArr1 = new Point(`, because I am in WPF :)